# R geom_forescast use case interpretation

Tags: r, forecast

Since I just started getting familiar with forecasting, so I stumbled upon the example [here](https://rdrr.io/cran/forecast/man/geom_forecast.html) based on which I have a few questions:

1. How can I forecast for the next `5` years?
2. What are the red and blue shaded areas around the forecast lines and what's the interpretation?
3. Why is there a break between the forecast lines and the historical lines?
4. What forecasting model does `geom_forecast` use?

`lungDeaths` data:

```
structure(c(2134, 1863, 1877, 1877, 1492, 1249, 1280, 1131, 1209, 
1492, 1621, 1846, 2103, 2137, 2153, 1833, 1403, 1288, 1186, 1133, 
1053, 1347, 1545, 2066, 2020, 2750, 2283, 1479, 1189, 1160, 1113, 
970, 999, 1208, 1467, 2059, 2240, 1634, 1722, 1801, 1246, 1162, 
1087, 1013, 959, 1179, 1229, 1655, 2019, 2284, 1942, 1423, 1340, 
1187, 1098, 1004, 970, 1140, 1110, 1812, 2263, 1820, 1846, 1531, 
1215, 1075, 1056, 975, 940, 1081, 1294, 1341, 901, 689, 827, 
677, 522, 406, 441, 393, 387, 582, 578, 666, 830, 752, 785, 664, 
467, 438, 421, 412, 343, 440, 531, 771, 767, 1141, 896, 532, 
447, 420, 376, 330, 357, 445, 546, 764, 862, 660, 663, 643, 502, 
392, 411, 348, 387, 385, 411, 638, 796, 853, 737, 546, 530, 446, 
431, 362, 387, 430, 425, 679, 821, 785, 727, 612, 478, 429, 405, 
379, 393, 411, 487, 574), .Dim = c(72L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(
    NULL, c("mdeaths", "fdeaths")), .Tsp = c(1974, 1979.91666666667, 
12), class = c("mts", "ts", "matrix"))
```

Code:

```
library(forecast)

# Data 
lungDeaths = cbind(mdeaths, fdeaths)

# Plot 
autoplot(lungDeaths) + geom_forecast()
```

Output:

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Comment: @Quinten, kindly see the updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the gap you can use `showgap`:

> If showgap=FALSE, the gap between the historical observations and the
> forecasts is removed.

Code:

```
library(forecast)
autoplot(lungDeaths) + 
  geom_forecast(showgap = FALSE)
```

Output:

[image]

To forecast 5 years you can use `h` to set the number of forecasts:

```
autoplot(lungDeaths) + 
  geom_forecast(h = 60, showgap = FALSE)
```

Output:

[image]

To remove the confidence intervals use `PI`:

> If FALSE, confidence intervals will not be plotted, giving only the
> forecast line.

```
library(forecast)
autoplot(lungDeaths) + 
  geom_forecast(h = 60, showgap = FALSE, PI = FALSE)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much, can you please add some explanation as to what `confidence intervals` tell us?

Comment: @Mandalorian, the confidence interval tells us what the mean of your estimate plus and minus the variation. So this area shows the range of values that are expected to fall in the confidence level. Mostly it is a 95% confidence interval. Here some extra info about confidence intervals: [link](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwib9dHsxtD4AhUYG-wKHRACCYgQFnoECBwQAw&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.scribbr.com%2Fstatistics%2Fconfidence-interval%2F&usg=AOvVaw319RcCUYFxWy3y8j9wxdiF).